# What lifecycle method should i use to listen for changes in state and update other state accordingly in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an app it have an array of data User selects timeSpan like `monthly`, `weekly` etc according to that array should be rendered on screen. I tried doing this in `componentWillUpdate` which i am not sure. But it gave me error.

There is a dropdown from where user selects `timespan` value. I don't know where should i put this so that it listen for changes in `timeSpan`
Any Help would be great

Here is my code .

```
if (this.state.timeSpan === "yearly") {
      const yearlyData = this.props.dispensingData.duration["yearly"];
      this.setState({ spanData: yearlyData });
    } else if (this.state.timeSpan === "weekly") {
      const weeklyData = this.props.dispensingData.duration["weekly"];
      this.setState({ spanData: weeklyData });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `setState` to pick a particular key from a prop. You should use `setState` for data that's e.g. user-entered.

```
const {timeSpan} = this.state;
let data;
if (timeSpan === "yearly" || timeSpan === "weekly") {
    data = this.props.dispensingData.duration[timeSpan];
}
```

in e.g. your render function should be enough for this usecase.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the componentDidUpdate method (docs here : https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate),

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.timespan !== this.state.timespan) {
    if (this.state.timeSpan === "yearly") {
      const yearlyData = this.props.dispensingData.duration["yearly"];
      this.setState({ spanData: yearlyData });
    } else if (this.state.timeSpan === "weekly") {
      const weeklyData = this.props.dispensingData.duration["weekly"];
      this.setState({ spanData: weeklyData });
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Here i need to compare timeSpan with `monthly` of `weekly`